# Publish and unpublish issue

Tags: php

I have this part of code in backend:

```
if (isset($_GET['publish']) || isset($_GET['unpublish'])) {
$message = "";
if (isset($_GET['publish'])) {
    $message = "Post published successfully";
    $post_id = $_GET['publish'];
} else if (isset($_GET['unpublish'])) {
    $message = "Post successfully unpublished";
    $post_id = $_GET['unpublish'];
}
togglePublishPost($post_id, $message);

}


function togglePublishPost($post_id, $message)
{
global $conn;
$sql = "UPDATE posts SET published=!published WHERE id=$post_id";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
    header("location: posts.php");
    exit(0);
    }
}
```

When I try to publish post from "https://....posts.php?publish=36" the page is refreshing and nothing happens. Also there is no logs in error file..Please help me with this..

P.S: the same if I try to unpublish the post. 
PHP v7.0

Comment: the error could be with `togglePublishPost()`

Comment: @tim can you please advise how to solve it?

Comment: what you posted works fine: https://ideone.com/Wn9RV4

Comment: @tim this code is working in xampp but not working in production (godaddy)..

Comment: this particular piece? or the whole thing?

Comment: @tim this particular piece.. this part is responsible for make post active or passive. when I choose the post passive in frontend the page just refreshing.

Comment: no, all the above does is is set 2 variables and then call another function,  as far as any one currently knows the problem could be in that function.

Comment: @tim I have added new code. Can you please check it now? Same, working on xampp, not working in godaddy....

Comment: that query is wrong `$sql = "UPDATE posts SET published=!published WHERE id=$post_id";`

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Replace: `(!published)` with `(not published)` like this:

`$sql = "UPDATE posts SET published = not published WHERE id=$post_id";`