# Publish button works on local server but not on my live web server

Tags: php, html

[image: screenshot of page]

This publish button is functioning on my Xampp local server fine, but when I use it on my live web server it does not do anything.

code from the page:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == "Admin" ): ?>
<td>
<?php if ($post['published'] == true): ?>
    <a class="btn unpublish"
        href="<?php echo BASE_URL .'/admin/posts.php' ?>?unpublish=<?php echo $post['id'] ?>">
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    </a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a class="btn published"
        href="<?php echo BASE_URL .'/admin/posts.php' ?>?published=<?php echo $post['id'] ?>">
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </a>
<?php endif ?>
</td>
```

And the function in my functions.php file

```
if (isset($_GET['published']) || isset($_GET['unpublish'])) {
$message = "";
if (isset($_GET['published'])) {
    $message = "Post published successfully";
    $post_id = $_GET['published'];
} 
else if (isset($_GET['unpublish'])) {
    $message = "Post successfully unpublished";
    $post_id = $_GET['unpublish'];
}
togglePublishPost($post_id, $message);
```

}

I really want this button to change the value for 'published' in my database table. 0 being unpublished and 1 being published

Error log reports this

[07-Feb-2021 09:33:35 Europe/Berlin] PHP Strict Standards:  strtotime(): We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CET/1.0/no DST' instead in /homepages/46/d856728078/htdocs/index.php on line 140
[07-Feb-2021 09:33:35 Europe/Berlin] PHP Strict Standards:  date(): We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CET/1.0/no DST' instead in /homepages/46/d856728078/htdocs/index.php on line 140

But none of the pages are about the page I'm questioning about.

I changed the default timezone and no longer receive that error, but didn't fix the problem.

Comment: What is `$post`? Do you get errors, do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: $post comes from a function returning all the 'posts' aka articles that are stored in my database

Comment: You need to trace your code to see what's going on: which actions are performed, which addresses are used, what is the network errors etc. There's no database-related code, so no one can tell you the reason

Comment: in localhost it does not append ?unpublish=xx at the end of the web address, but online it does

Comment: After enabling logs, the only thing that I see is this; [07-Feb-2021 09:33:35 Europe/Berlin] PHP Strict Standards:  strtotime(): We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CET/1.0/no DST' instead in /homepages/46/d856728078/htdocs/index.php on line 140
[07-Feb-2021 09:33:35 Europe/Berlin] PHP Strict Standards:  date(): We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CET/1.0/no DST' instead in /homepages/46/d856728078/htdocs/index.php on line 140

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer to my problem on another page here in stackoverflow.
[Answer for publish/unpublish not functioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55680220/publish-and-unpublish-issue/57445279#57445279)

the problem is this line of code in the functions.php file

```
$sql = "UPDATE posts SET published=!published WHERE id=$post_id";
```

Apparently, this line is wrong and this line should be used instead.

```
$sql = "UPDATE posts SET published = not published WHERE id=$post_id";
```

I hope this can help other people who have a similar issue.